# Crowd GPS Bluetooth 4.0 universal database

Tags: android, bluetooth, gps, bluetooth-lowenergy, crowdsourcing

With all these different "crowd gps" bluetooth 4.0 tags floating around, and each with their own software, I was wondering if there is a "universal" database or software?

If I buy a Tile unit, and the guy next to me has a TrackR unit, they are not compatible.  I was hoping to find some "universal" software that would work with any bluetooth 4.0 tag.  If there was a universal database, the crowd GPS idea would be huge.

Has anyone seen anything like this?